# How to keep the label of Semantic UI dropdown

Tags: user-interface, semantic-ui

A Semantic UI `Search Dropdown` can look like this:

[image: Semantic UI Search Dropdown]

I can easily follow the template to create these. However, once a selection is made the default text is replaced. I need something will replace the icon with a label or text, so that the end result is that dropdown retains a label describing what it is after selection.

The icons serve this purpose for simple usages, but how do I use an icon to indicate say *first_name*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Settings for Dropdowns](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/settings)

Please refer to this link.  It presents you with several options for the dropdown **action**.  By default it is *activate*.  If you change the **action** setting to *select* it should give you your desired functionality.

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown({action: 'select'});
```